# Using django-filter to filter by a single date

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am trying to filter time ranges (like `'2014-12-27' < time <= '2014-12-28'`) using only one parameter.

I currently use a url like this for getting a single day

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/movieapi/movieshowtime/?mixtime=2014-12-27&maxtime=2014-12-28
```

I would like to be able to do something like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/movieapi/movieshowtime/?timerange=2014-12-27
```

But it does not work. The filterset that I am currently using is

```
class MovieShowtimeFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    mixtime = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(name="movietime",lookup_type='gte')
    maxtime = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(name="movietime",lookup_type='lt')
    timerange = django_filters.DateRangeFilter(name='movietime')

    class Meta:
        model = MovieShowtime
        fields = ['mixtime','maxtime','timerange']
```

Answer (score 4):

The `DateRangeFilter` provided by `django-filter` allows you to filter across common date ranges like "today", "the past week", "last month", etc. It does not allow you to filter a queryset down to a specific date.

You should be able to do this with a custom filter though.

```
from django_filters.filters import DateFilter

class WithinDateFilter(DateFilter):

    def filter(self, qs, value):
        from datetime import timedelta

        if value:
            date_value = value.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)

            filter_lookups = {
                "%s__range" % (self.name, ): (
                    value,
                    value + timedelta(days=1),
                ),
            }

            qs = qs.filter(**filter_lookups)

        return qs
```

This should allow you to pass in the single date through the url, and have the query be filtered to only times within that specific date.

```
class MovieShowtimeFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    timerange = WithinDateFilter(name='movietime')

    class Meta:
        model = MovieShowtime
        fields = ['mixtime','maxtime','timerange']
```

Comment: Thank you very much.But I don't know how to merge this with my ````MovieShowtimeFilter```` Can you describe it more clearly. Sorry my ability is not so well